# Google Workspace marketplace SDK universal navigation URL custom parameters

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have our products published in Google Workspace Marketplace. When accessing the apps from Google bar we get the domain of the user by including ${DOMAIN_NAME} in *Universal navigation URL* in Google Workspace Marketplace SDK.

Likewise is there any parameter we can include in the Universal Navigation URL to get the email of the user when accessing the services from Google bar?

Answer (score 1):

The Universal Navigation URL only accepts a DOMAIN parameter. If you want the email address you'll need to implement OpenID support.